# Should using USB tethering along with my existing Wi-Fi connection boost the internet speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb

I have unlimited mobile data on LTE. I tethered my phone's connection to my laptop which was already running my home WiFi. I expected this would sort of create a bridged connection and I'd get an increased speed on my laptop. However, this did not happen.
Could anyone explain why? Or could anyone explain what should I do if I want to use my WiFi and mobile data in parallel?

Comment: You need a load balancer to speed up your connection. Either a software one or a hardware solution. There are several programs available such as Connectify Dispatch Hotspot, Speedify etc. JUST Bridging your networks wont increase the speed

Comment: What speed, specifically, do you want to increase? Your general browsing speed? A single download's speed?

Comment: @DanielB I was under the impression that the browsing speed and the download speed are one and the same (since a web page is technically downloaded on your device)?

Comment: A regular download uses a single HTTP connection. Opening a web page uses many HTTP connections and many more requests. These connections could easily be distributed to multiple Internet uplinks. However, with a fast enough uplink, the subjective speed is mostly the result of latency. Because of the end-to-end principle, the single-connection download cannot be accelerated easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, it works for me.

1. Open Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter Settings
2. Select your LAN interface -> right click -> properties
3. Click on Internet Protocol TCP/IP Version 4-> properties-> go to advanced
4. Uncheck the Automatic Metric and enter a value(say 16)
5. Do the same steps for your WIFI interface

It does not do much on ping timing but boosts the download speeds.

Comment: This is essentially a refinement of Adam Horniks answer (with much clearer markup). It does make ssome assumptions though which should be stated explicitly. e.g. using regular TCP/IP a single file transfer does not go faster (E.g. downloading an iso from a website). 2). It also meantions ping (ICMP echo request) which has very little to do with download speeds.

Comment: @Hennes Well ping has nothing to do with download speeds. But i was trying to imply that multiple connections won't improve ping timings.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply boost your browsing / downloading experience by connecting via multiple interfaces. Due to cost metric Windows uses only one interface at the time (the one with lowest cost metric = interface metric + gateway metric).
Solution might be to configure both your interfaces to have same cost metric, Windows should then split the traffic between both interfaces based on their current load. Please note that for one connection (eg. downloading a certain file over HTTP) only one interface can be used, you should see the difference when downloading more files at the time.
How to manually configure metric on certain interface: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771274(v=ws.11).aspx
more on this topic:
http://www.sortbyte.com/software-programs/networking/network-manager/kb/1001